# Computer turns on but there's no signal in monitor (and after some attempts it works normally)

Tags: boot, ssd, graphics-card

Sometimes, when I turn my computer on, it lights up but the monitor has no signal (when the PC is off it says "No cable connected"). I then shut it down via keyboard using `ALT+F4` and `Enter` and retry. Some attempts later it works normally.

Sometimes when it turns on, it starts an analysis of the C: volume (a 120 GB SSD).

Specifics: (OS: Windows 10)

- CPU: Intel i5 2550k
- GPU: nVidia GTX 770
- MB: Asrock P67 Pro3
- PSU: Corsair C750M

Comment: Monitor model? Interface (both on monitor and on videoadapter)?

Comment: I have got two of them actually: a 40" Samsung TV and a LG monitor: DM2350D. What do you mean by interface?

Comment: DVI (A,I,D)? HDMI? DP? Try to alter. And check (try another) cable.

Comment: Monitor is HDMI, TV is DVI

Comment: Have you found a solution? I experience the same with my system (Ryzen 1700, Linux + Windows) after I replaced my two monitors with brand-new Super Ultra Wide LG38. I have never experienced this on my setup, I have the same graphics card so it is apparently something wrong in the monitor itself. When I am shutting down the system and it goes back to text mode (when in Linux) the monitor then detects the signal so apparently everything is working and restart is not needed I just need to figure out what makes the monitor to wake up and start operating.